# How to extract the balance qty

Tags: sql

I hv a table like this:-

```
    TABLE A
    --------------------------------
    Date       |  Serial    | Qty   
    --------------------------------
    20110101       ABC        1 
    20110102       ABC       -1 
    20110105       ABC        1 
    20110106       ABC        1 
    20110108       ABC       -1
```

I need to know what's the balance qty of ABC (based on FIFO) using SQL & the final output will look something like this:-

```
Date            Serial      Qty 
20110106         ABC         1
```

Thanks.

Comment: The question makes no sense. How do you want it to decide what date and size to show?

Comment: Also, what database platofrm?

Comment: OK, editing the 1/8/2011 row to have a size of 25 and leaving the desired output of 24 has me completely confused.  If this is a FIFO queue, presumably the inventory was 23 on 1/1, then decreased to 0 on 1/2.  It increased to 22 on 1/5 and to 46 on 1/6.  Then it was decreased to 21 on 1/8.  Those 21 units happen to be from the 1/6 order, but what happens if there are units from multiple orders left?

Comment: @Justin - should not look at size. On FIFO queue, inventory was 1 on 1/1, then decreased to 0 on 1/2. It increased back to 1 on 1/5 and 2 on 1/6. Then it decreased to 1 on 1/8. That balance of 1 unit happened to be from 1/6. So, the system will just need to display the full details of 1/6 which is:- Date Serial  Qty Size
20110106         ABC     1  24

Comment: @Bob - OK.  Then what does `SIZE` represent if not the size of the order?  And why would the 1/6 row be returned and not the 1/8 row or the 1/5 row?

Comment: @Justin - Lets assume there is no SIZE (I hv removed it). So, is it still possible to extract the info as 1/6 ?

Comment: @Bob - You still need to explain why we would extract the 1/6 row and not the 1/5 row or the 1/8 row.  The 1/6 row isn't the last row, it's not the first row.  I don't see anything special about that row based on the data you're providing.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to pick out one record from the table?  Like this?

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE Date = '20110106' AND Serial = 'ABC'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like

```
SELECT serial, max(date), 1 qty, sum( qty*size ) size
  FROM tableA
 GROUP BY serial
```

If you can have a negative final output, whatever database engine you're using should have something equivalent to Oracle's SIGN and ABS functions

```
SELECT serial, max(date), sign( sum( qty*size ) ) qty, abs( sum( qty*size ) ) size
  FROM tableA
 GROUP BY serial
```

Note that I'm guessing that you want the total remaining quantity as of the last day and that you get this by netting the positive quantities against the negative quantities for all the rows in the table for a particular `SERIAL`.  I think this is close but I'm not sure how you're getting the DATE value

Comment: i hv edited the above question & the suggested answer may not be suitable, especially in terms of size. Possible to tweak it ?

Comment: @Bob - OK.  I'm now more confused by the edits to the sample data.  I posted a comment on the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
select Serial, sum(qty) as Total, Size from table_a group by Serial, Size
```

would give you:

```
TABLE A
Serial  Total Size
  ABC     0    23
  ABC     0    22
  ABC     1    24
```

you can, of course, add a where clause to restrict the query further:

```
select Serial, sum(qty) as Total, Size from table_a where Serial='ABC' and Size=24 group by Serial, Size
```

would give you information for Serial ABC with Size 24, only:

```
Serial  Total Size
  ABC     1    24
```

or you can filter out anything with Total of zero using a having clause:

```
select Serial, sum(qty) as Total, Size from table_a group by Serial, Size having sum(qty) <> 0

Serial  Total Size
  ABC     1    24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT MAX(date) AS date, serial, ABS(SUM(qty * size)) AS size, SIGN(SUM(qty * size)) AS qty
    FROM your_table
GROUP BY serial
```

Comment: i hv edited the above question & the suggested answer may not be suitable, especially in terms of size. Possible to tweak it ?